# R Shiny plot will show once but not update with new info

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

first question on here so I hope that I am giving enough detail. I am trying to build a reactive ggplot to display sales for a given IAG (age group), Category, and property type. The plot will show just as it should in the main panel however, when I change a value in each of the lists under each input fields and hit the update button, there is no change to the plot. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Also Note: some of the Property values in the data set do have spaces in between two words and have given me issues when running this outside of a shiny app... example: Ranger Woman as a filter value always gives me an error code. The same could be said with any category that has a hyphen example: bed-sheets.

```
library(shiny)
library(lattice, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(gridExtra, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(RColorBrewer, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(readxl, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggplot2, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(data.table, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(stats, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(readxl, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

da <- read_excel("Order_Export.xlsx")
da$OrderDate = as.Date(da$OrderDate)
da$OrderDate
da$Category = as.factor(da$Category)
da$IAG = as.character(da$IAG)
da$Property = as.factor(da$Property)
da$IAG[da$IAG == "Men, Women"] <- "Adult"

PL_C = da %>% distinct(Property)%>%
  arrange(Property,desc(Property))%>%
  as.data.frame()
PL_C <- as.list(PL_C$Property)
names(PL_C) <- PL_C$property

C_C = da %>% distinct(Category)%>%
  arrange(Category,desc(Category))%>%
  as.data.frame()
C_C <- as.list(C_C$Category)
names(C_C) <- C_C$Category

IAG_C = da %>% distinct(IAG)%>%
  arrange(IAG,desc(IAG))%>%
  as.data.frame()
IAG_C <- as.list(IAG_C$IAG)
names(IAG_C) <- IAG_C$IAG
```

**Here is the ui.R**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title="Trends Display"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("updt","Update"),
      selectInput("PL","Select Property",choices = PL_C),
      selectInput("CAT","Select Category",choices = C_C),
      selectInput("IAG","Select Age Group",choices = IAG_C)
      ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot2"))
    )
)
```

**Here is the server.R**

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    data <- eventReactive(input$updt, {
        da %>% 
          filter(Property == input$PL) %>%
          filter(Category == input$CAT) %>%
          filter(IAG == input$IAG) %>%
          as.data.frame()
        da

    subset(da,select=c(OrderDate,QtyShipped,Year,Property,Category,IAG))
    da$Month = month(as.factor(da$OrderDate))
    da$Month = month.abb[da$Month]
    da$Month = factor(da$Month, levels=c("Jan", "Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"))
    aggregate(QtySent ~ Month+Year, da, sum)
     })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data(), aes(x=Month, y=QtyShipped, group=factor(Year), colour=factor(Year)))+
        geom_line()+
        geom_point()
    })
  }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample data?

Comment: It seems the output from `filter` is never used. You have `da %>% filter(...)` in `server.R` but never assign the result to any variable. Therefore, `data()` does not change with the inputs.